# Laravel blade inline section

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to duplicate a piece of html in my blade template but it's so small that I don't want to create a new file. Can I create a section in the same file that I use it? for example:

```
@section('small')
    <div>small piece of html</div>
@endsection

@include('small')
<div>some html here</div>
@include('small')
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking to make a [Component](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#components-and-slots) here?

`@component('small') @endcomponent`

Comment: I need to define it in the same file I'm using it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `@stack` and `@push` is what you need instead of `@section`
Let's say you're going to use that on other file

**Page 1:**

```
@stack('small')
```

**Page 2 :**

```
@push('small')
    <div>small piece of html</div>
@endpush
@push('small')
     <div>some html here</div>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Component](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#components-and-slots) with Laravel and make your template in a example.blade.php and set your variables in the component, and send the variables to the component while calling it like:

```
@component('alert', ['foo' => 'bar'])
    ...
@endcomponent
```

So it's in a different file but while sending the variables to the component, it can be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean duplicate @section? if yes, so create @yield with another name, and call both sections in the same template.

**Page 1:**

```
@yield('section1')
@yield('section2')
```

**Page 2 :**

```
@section('section1')
    <div>small piece of html</div>
@endsection

@section('section2')
     <div>some html here</div>
@endsection
```